# Change Url Params

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, parameters, language

I got lost here with an issue when I try to achieve a case which a user can click on a button and change the language of a form in visual force page.

I know a way which works but don't support IE browsers -( which is kind of a problem for my users) with the **URLSearchParams** JS method.

The second way I tried is to put the language param for the apex:page :

**language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}"** :

```
<apex:page id="formPageId" controller="PaymentFormController" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}">
```

and then, to get the lang param with js function and set it to the value that clicked.

for Example :

```
const param = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
param.set('lang','es')
```

My issue here is when I try to refresh the page with my new url (new param that i just had changed).

Anyone have any idea or a better way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use action:function to pass language param in URL and re-render whole page by providing `id` to the page? I have provided page with id `formPageId` and re-rendering in action function.

```
<apex:page id="formPageId" controller="PaymentFormController" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}" >

    <apex:form>
        <!-- Define the JavaScript function sayHello-->
        <apex:actionFunction name="changeLanguage" action="{!changeLanguageApex}" rerender="formPageId" status="myStatus">
             <apex:param id="lang" name="lang" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction> 
    </apex:form>

    <script>
        function onbuttonClick() {
            changeLanguage('es');
        }
    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="onbuttonClick()">Change Language</button>
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class PaymentFormController{


    public PageReference changeLanguageApex(){
        PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();

        pageRef.setRedirect(true);

       return pageRef;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but now what?
after I get the lang param inside the controller, how can I achieve the translations of all the custom labels and the labels of my objects inside the  page?

Comment: you are using re-render right? so page will auto re-render and get updated custom lable?

Comment: Yes I am, and also I'm using the language param :   language="{!IF(ISNULL(lang),'en_US',lang)}".. but still its not change the lables..

Comment: You have to refresh the page by passing lang param so that when lables are fetched again thy wil be translated,

Comment: Thanks! I had a mistake with my re render  - Now Its working - not with a pageReference function but only with a {get;set;} param and action function.